# Should I use Keep-Alive when screen-scraping?

Tags: php, curl, screen-scraping

Is it recommended to work with persistent connections when screen-scraping?  What are the possible advantages/disadvantages?

I'm using PHP/cURL to scrape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't make that much of a difference. The real performance decision you need to make is concurrent scraping. Because, persistent or not, a single connection can only process 1 request/response at a time.

Which brings me to my next point:

> I'm using PHP/cURL to scrape.

PHP is probably the wrong tool for this job. It's not very good at concurrency. Or, at least, the default build isn't.

Comment: `PHP is probably the wrong tool for this job.` -> Why? For some things it would be perfectly fine.  It would be helpful to know what cases you believe it to be bad for and why.

Comment: @Renesis most cases of screen scraping I've seen don't need to be done at runtime. There are very few use-cases where you should be blocking the response by curling out from the web application layer.

Comment: This case does need to be done at runtime because its live data.  And we are using multi_curl to do concurrent scraping where possible.

Comment: @babonk in that case, the cut/dry answer for you .. keep-alive won't really help (or hurt). Your keys to high performance are concurrency and, if possible, caching.